# tf dir There is no working folder mapping for

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tf-cli

I'm writing build script and am trying to get files from TFS through command line, but couldnt get them working. Always get message "All files up to date", while no file exists.

I delete existing workspace and create new workspace and map to local folder. All of it works without error. However after that I'm not able to get the files. What could be wrong. What other steps I need to do to diagnose it.

Below is the list of commands and results:

```
 D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf workfold
 ====================================================================

 Workspace:  xantworkspace

Collection: https://dev.company.com/tfs/

 $/allProjects/MobileProject/Dev: D:\temp\tfs\Dev

 D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf dir


 There is no working folder mapping for D:\temp\tfs\Dev.


 D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf get

 All files up to date.


 D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf get /all

 All files up to date.

 D:\temp\tfs\Dev>cd ..

 D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf get /all /force

All files up to date.

D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf get /all /force /overwrite
All files up to date.

D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf get /all /force /overwrite /recursive

All files up to date.

D:\temp\tfs\Dev>tf get /all /force /overwrite /recursive /version:T

All files up to date.
```

In TFS, $/allProjects/MobileProject/Dev has files, folders under it.

Comment: I'd suggest to check the working folder mappings in your workspace using team explorer. The 'tf dir' should return items stored in $/allProjects/MobileProject/Dev. So if it does not return anything it's logical that tf get does not download anything.

Comment: I have the same problem. Issuing a `dir` command returns the contents on the server but whenever I try to get the latest version it just says `All files up to date`

Answer (score 0):

You're not using Team City by chance?  If so, Team City has two different kinds of agents.  One creates a workspace that is not TFS-centric (default).  The other connects with TFS and can be used like a normal workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar experiences with TFS before when I've been given read but not write permissions.  Giving my user account read/write was the only fix that let me actually get the files.